# Why the destroy fragment is always save the listview position?

Tags: android

I use the `ViewPager` and `Fragment`, 
     Adapter:`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`
     `offScreenPagerLimit`:1
I want to know why the `ListView` in `Fragment` layout always save its position? how do i let it forget the state?

```
public class BaseFragmentStatePagerAdapter<T extends Fragment> extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
static final boolean DEBUG = true; 

private String[] mTitles;
private List<T> mFragments;

/**
 * @param fm
 */
public BaseFragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<T> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    mFragments = fragments;
}

/**
 * @param fm
 */
public BaseFragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String[] titles, List<T> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    mFragments = fragments;
    mTitles = titles;
}

@Override
public T getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragments == null ? 0 : mFragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    if (mTitles == null || mTitles.length == 0) {
        return super.getPageTitle(position);
    } else {
        return mTitles[position];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe since you're using the FragmentStatePagerAdapter the state of your fragment will be saved, even when you call a manual destroy on it.

> Implementation of PagerAdapter that uses a Fragment to manage each
>   page. This class also handles saving and restoring of fragment's
>   state.

Same goes for all the data contained within that Fragment, including the ListView and it's saved index.

One solution would be to disable the saving of the listView.

```
ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
listView.setSaveEnabled(false);
```

I hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

If `offScreenPagerLimit`:1 the `ViewPager` will maintain the state of the `Fragment` currently shown(evidently) and one to the left and one to the right.

Comment: Not the cache fragment, i say the destroy!

Comment: So in your case if you are displaying Fragment at position 0, Fragment at position 2 is not destroyed?

Comment: Just think i click all the tabs, current is tab3, click tab0, tab0's fragment is destroy, but the listview in tab0 still remember it's position!

Comment: So your `ListView` is created again when you return to tab0 or...?

Comment: Yes, the layout is new inflate.

Comment: A workaround is to scroll to the top of the list after your inflate using        listView.setSelection(0);

Comment: yes i can do it, but can see the animation! UE is bad!